# She will be up at night studying. (studying is gerund or present participle?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> She will be up at night studying.

Should I understand the sentence above like

> "She will be up studying at night." or

should I understand that like

> "She will be up for night studying."

My guess is that 'studying' is a present participle and not a gerund.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, "studying" is a participle there, not a noun. It's in the future continuous *[ "will be" + present participle ]*.

"Night studying" isn't a compound noun here because "at night" is an adverbial of time, unconnected to "studying".

Your first re-written sentence has the same meaning as the original.

Comment: 'at' is a preposition and after that noun or gerund can come in the light of grammar. That is, 'studying' is a gerund.

Comment: No, the word after "at" is "night", not "studying". "Studying" goes with "will be" to form the future continuous. It's a present participle, not a gerund.

Comment: _Will_ can also [refer to a habit](https://www.grammaring.com/modals-to-express-habits-will-would-used-to) as well as the future.

Comment: @gotube the reason why I told you the 'studying' is a gerund was that why 'night studying' itself can't form a compound noun.

Comment: @gomadeng That would mean "studying" is *not* a gerund. A gerund is a noun. This verb is clearly a verb, and not a noun.

Comment: Soccer exercising could form a compound noun.

Comment: @gomadeng Yes it could. How does that affect the part of speech of "studying", which is not part of a compound noun in that sentence?